ItemsView: How to disable each item's hover effect?
I have implemented a ItemsView according to the descriptions in the WinUI 3 Gallery app.
How do I disable the hover effect that occurs when mouse over each item (item becomes darker)?
Thanks

ItemsView uses ItemContainer for each item. Overriding ItemContainerPointerOverBackground should work:
<ItemsView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ItemsView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="ItemContainerPointerOverBackground"
            Color="Transparent" />
    </ItemsView.Resources>
</ItemsView>

You can learn more about it in the generic.xaml.

Thanks for a quick answer! How/Where does one find these keys?

You can find them in the generic.xaml. Search for ItemContainerPointerOverBackground.
